# merging two arrays in php from mysql and converting to json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have two arrays which i want to merge  and map the values together where it's id's are same . The problem is when i use array_merge function it only merges two arrays and resulting json is does not fit my model in android.

Here is php function :-

```
 public function   getfromorders(){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM p_orders';
    $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $query -> execute(array());
    $pro1=array();
    $orders =array();
    while($data = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
      $orders[] = $data;
     $pro1[] = $data -> p_id;     
    }
    $pro=array();
    foreach ($pro1 as $id0) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE p_id = :p_id';
    $query2 = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $query2 -> execute(array(':p_id' => $id0));
        while($products = $query2 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
        $pro[] = $products;
        }
    }
    return  array_merge($pro,$orders);
 }
```

Here is resulting json :-

```
    {
 "products": [
  {
  "p_id": "4",
  "p_name": "Data Structures and algorithm in C++",
  "p_info": "Adam Drozdek",
  "p_sold": "Book Available : 20",
  "p_image": "http://www.buildupcareer.com/gauti/Hunt/Food.jpg",
  "p_type": "Veg",
  "p_star": "0"
},
{
  "p_id": "12",
  "p_name": " Kadai Paneer",
  "p_info": "An Indian vegetarian dish made with cottage cheese cooked with tomatoes-onions-bell peppers- and a blend of Indian spices",
  "p_sold": "Spicy",
  "p_image": "http://www.buildupcareer.com/gauti/Hunt/Burger.jpg",
  "p_type": "Start-ups",
  "p_star": "0"
},
{
  "email": "7827789246",
  "p_id": "4",
  "noi": "1",
  "order_id": "36"
},
{
  "email": "7827789246",
  "p_id": "12",
  "noi": "1",
  "order_id": "35"
    }
 ],
 "result": "success"
 }
```

I want that resulting json should merge the (p_id,email,noi ,order_id) with the (p_id,p_name,p_info......) without changing the mysql database  . Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my expected json:-

```
   {
   "products": [
{
  "p_id": "4",
  "p_name": "Data Structures and algorithm in C++",
  "p_info": "Adam Drozdek",
  "p_sold": "Book Available : 20",
  "p_image": "http://www.buildupcareer.com/gauti/Hunt/Food.jpg",
  "p_type": "Veg",
  "p_star": "0",
  "email": "7827789246",
  "noi": "1",
  "order_id": "36"
},
{
  "p_id": "12",
  "p_name": " Kadai Paneer",
  "p_info": "An Indian vegetarian dish made with cottage cheese cooked with tomatoes-onions-bell peppers- and a blend of Indian spices",
  "p_sold": "Spicy",
  "p_image": "http://www.buildupcareer.com/gauti/Hunt/Burger.jpg",
  "p_type": "Start-ups",
  "p_star": "0",
  "email": "7827789246",
  "p_id": "12",
  "noi": "1",
  "order_id": "35"
  }
 ],
"result": "success"
 }
```

Comment: Show us some example of `$pro`, `$products` and the expected output.

Comment: So, there's a problem here: What if multiple orders are for the same product? What would your JSON look like then?

Comment: I have edited it and  included my expected output.

Comment: for multiple orders i have included noi(no. of items)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can construct your JSON:

```
while($products = $query2 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $newElement = array();
    foreach($products as $key => value) {
        if ($key !== "p_id") {
            $newElement[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    if (!isset($pro[$products["p_id"]])) {
        $pro["p_id"] = array();
    }
    $pro["p_id"][]=$newElement;
}
```

Note that to avoid duplicating `p_id`, I have used it as a key. Each key is associated with an array of items.

Comment: i have to just merge the arrays .